# Installing glibc 2.3 for mysql server

Tags: mysql, glibc

I need to install mysql server and client for a project of mine so i downloaded the MySQL-client-5.1.61-1.glibc23.i386.rpm for the client and MySQL-server-5.1.61-1.glibc23.i386.rpm for server.
I followed the instructions on mysql site and it says I need the glibc 2.3 libraries and when i try to install it gives me among other: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by MySQL-client-5.1.61-1.glibc23.i386

I didn't find a way to install it on the web and i don't really know how to build/compile it myself..

What to do? How do I easily install glibc 2.3?

*using ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Why not use ubuntu's built-in package manager to install mysql?

Comment: Thank you i didn't really think about it lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always best to use your distro's package manager for installing services such as mysql, apache, bind, etc. But there are times where you need to install some packages manually.

For example, in CentOS, the version installed through `yum` (centos package manager) is currently 5.3.3, but I prefer to run a newer version (5.3.8), so in this example, I would download and manually compile PHP outside of the package manager. However, I do take care not to pollute my system, and always set custom `PREFIX=/my/custom/path` flags for every package I manually install, this allows me to remove, and update without affecting core system packages.

I would also suggest you look at [Percona MySQL](http://www.percona.com/). It's a custom build of MySQL which enhances performance and admin features.